# C# wrapping blocking io with task to make async

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, io, task-parallel-library

I have a web api call that I want to get great throughput on so I am wrapping the I/O with a Task in the hopes to make it async. However, I am not sure that it does want I looking for.

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]DataRequest request)
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            service.SendRequestToQueue(request);
        });

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Accepted);
    }
```

I Feel like this is not the right way to do this. It does get the I/O off the the requesting thread but is still handled by a thread in the application and not the kernel. Am I right? Is there a better way to do this other then making async and await all the way down?

Comment: Not really.  You should generally be either entirely synchronous, or entirely asynchronous.  Async over sync (which is what this is) or sync over async (synchronously blocking on an asynchronous operation) are both very problematic, and should be avoided at all possible costs.

Comment: What exactly is the reasoning for this? It looks like the client is just sending requests and not waiting for the result? If that's the case then this is as good an approach as any. 

I'm not sure why Servy thinks that you should avoid async approaches at all costs. That doesn't seem like a reasonable thing to say. Obviously if you're going to start doing work asynchronously you're going to expose a new set of prooblems, but async await is available for a reason. If your intent is to hit it and forget it then this is a good solution. But if you need to wait for a result. Just use async await.

Comment: @Callan: It's not a good solution; [it's very dangerous](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/12/returning-early-from-aspnet-requests.html), as I explain on my blog.

Comment: I think that's an excellent blog post. I am simply working on the assumption that he didn't care what the result is. Throwing an exception in a child thread can shut the app pool down, but with the proper exception handling he shouldnt have to worry about it. Granted, in the vast majority of cases, you need to wait for a result, and creating a child thread and waiting for it to return is pointless. But on the off change he really doesn't care what comes back, this would be a viable way to send work off to the server and forget about it. But I will agree, there are VERY few use cases for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct solution, as @Servy commented, is to use `async` all the way down. In particular, on ASP.NET, you should avoid `Task.Run` and `Task.Factory.StartNew`. As you suspected, using `await` with a task queued to the thread pool will not give you any scalability benefit at all.

Your code as it currently stands returns the response while continuing to process the request in-memory. This is extremely dangerous, as I explain [on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/12/returning-early-from-aspnet-requests.html) and [in a recent CodeMash talk](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/01/achievement-unlocked-speak-at-codemash.html) (see the slides under the "Gotchas" section entitled "Returning Early").